# Unchecked lastError value: Error: Promised response from onMessage listener went out of scope

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, firefox-addon-webextensions, content-script

The addon code was working perfectly fine and now I get error - `““Unchecked lastError value: Error: Promised response from onMessage listener went out of scope””` .

[image]

**content-script code:**

```
chrome.runtime.sendMessage({
                "url": theURL,
                "base": scriptURL
});
```

**background script:**

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function (message) {
    console.log('Inside Listener');

});
```

I am not getting

> Inside Listener

in console. This was working fine a few days ago, the code is unchanged !!

Comment: You seem to be looking at the wrong console. The output of the background script can be seen in its own devtools, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38920982) for details. Anyway, the fragments of code in your question are fine and thus aren't enough to diagnose the problem.

Comment: Thanks, that worked. Strangely, `alert('hi');` in the background script which was not firing earlier suddenly started executing!!

Comment: In my case, I was returning true at the end of the onMessage's listener. Removing that solved my problem